# Regular expression for html only applied on text not on html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to implement condition regEx: `(<.*?>|<\/.*?>)`, it will find all the tag from html but i need to apply conditionally

for example i have a tag like

```
<div all>welcome caption </div>
<p>caption</p>
<caption>caption</caption>
```

the regex i need to find only 'caption' which highlighted

Comment: I think this is why regex on HTML is a **Bad Idea™**

Comment: @fronthem i want only caption

Comment: thanks every one, I got answer regex: `(\balgebra\b)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)`